# Are there any studies that show impact of compulsory voting on outcomes?

Tags: voting-systems

Are there any studies that show impact of compulsory voting on outcomes?

By outcomes, I mean (all **other** things being held equal), whether compulsory voting results in better HDI, or economic growth, or any other "well-being" measure that's reliably measurable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several people are have published work on compulsory voting and income inequality. In a broad cross-national [paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1468-0343.2008.00336.x/abstract?deniedAccessCustomisedMessage=&userIsAuthenticated=false) (Chong and Olivera, 2008. "Does Compulsory Voting Help Equalize Incomes? *Economics and Politics* 20.3. "), enforceable compulsory voting is associated with greater income equality as measured by the GINI coefficient.

"Enforceable" is an important caveat - many countries with compulsory voting policies don't enforce them well. [This page](http://www.idea.int/vt/compulsory_voting.cfm) shows countries, their voting requirements, and voter turnout figures. Countries with compulsory voting range from about 70% - 80% voter turnout. The possible penalties for not voting range from nothing at all to imprisonment or losing the right to vote altogether.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you add a brief couple of quotes from the synopsis as well as actual paper title, if the link goes dead

Comment: As in all soft sciences a proper experiment is hard to run; However for this exact scenario there has been a study where compulsory voting has been REMOVED and how that changed Gini which comes to the same conclusion: http://sites.dartmouth.edu/jcarey/files/2013/02/CH-Compulsory-Voting-Income-Inequality-010214.pdf

Comment: "Countries with compulsory voting range from about 70% - 80% voter turnout" Last I recall Australia manages about 97% with enforced voting?

Comment: @inappropriateCode - It's hard to know what to do with that. It might be true, but the link supporting the 70-80% turnout figure is dead. If I can dig up the original source, I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: @indigochild According to this from [the Australian Electoral Commission](http://www.aec.gov.au/About_AEC/Publications/voting/index.htm#rates): "The turnout at Australian elections has never fallen below 90% since the introduction of compulsory voting in 1924." Though I'm not sure if Australia is outlier compared to other nations.